# How to properly update/re-render a component that is not a child React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using a react-navigation. More specifically, I have a materialTabNavigator nested inside of a drawerNavigator. Each tab is in itself a stackNavigator. I have a button in homeScreen, that navigates to makePost.js. There I take in information and store it to Async storage using a simple wrapper.

In Posts.js there's a FlatList displaying each post as a component. The data for the FlatList is initially set correctly after making a request from Async Storage. The problem is that this only happens when the app is first opened. I have tried many different approaches to solve this. The only way so far I've found is to continuously setState in ComponentDidUpdate() in Posts.js. Obviously this is problematic, because it re-renders constantly. I can set a flag to stop is from rendering, but then it will not re-render again.

Ultimately, what I'd like to happen is that when I hit the user is done entering their information and is ready to make a post, they hit the button in makePost.js, and the data in the FlatList of Posts.js is update.

I've tried to pass parameters using navigation, does not work, parameters get lost somewhere, probably because of the nested navigators.

I could really used some guidance on the proper way to accomplish this.

( Navigators; not sure why this is forcing to one line )

---drawer
    --tabNav
    -home
      homeScreen.js
      makePost.js
    -posts
      posts.js
    -messages
  --drawer1
  --drawer2

```
//Posts.js
export default class Posts extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    rows: [
      {id: 0, text: "dog"},
    ],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadState();
  }

  loadState = () => {
    var value = store.get('posts').then((res => {
        if (res === null) {
          res = [{id: 0, text: "default"}]
        } else {
          res = res 
        }
        this.setState({rows: res})
    }))
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.loadState();
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <BoardTab style={styles.row} />
    )} 

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.view}>
        <FlatList
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          style={styles.container}
          data={this.state.rows}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={extractKey}
         >
        </FlatList>
        <BoardScreenFooter />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And Posts.js button looks like this:

```
        <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={ () => {
            this._onPressButton
            this.storeFunc(this.state.newPost)
            const retval = this.state.rows

            this.props.navigation.navigate('Board', 
            {rowsID: retval});

            }
          }>
          <Icon
            reverse
            name='md-camera'
            type='ionicon'
            color='green'
          size={12}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>  



  storeFunc(newObj) {
    newObj.id = newObj.id + 1
    store.push('posts', newObj)
    store.get('posts').then((res) => {
      this.setState({rows: res})
    })
  }
```

Comment: That's why Redux was introduced to solve this issue regarding on state management. React-Navigation should be implemented together with Redux. Take a time to learn it because it's worth to be used in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Rapidly, i would say: use Redux. It alloq you to have global state in your app, which mean you can access the state anywhere (And also set them anywhere)
When opening the app, you get the data from the AsyncStore into the Redux store. You listen to the redux state (Which will be a props in your component) and display your list. When modifying your list in the other tab, you need to do 2 things:

1. Store the new data in the AsyncStorage
2. Update the state in the redux store. Since Posts.js will be listening at the redux store (as a props), it will re-render each time your data will change

Comment: Okay I will dive further into Redux, but i'm a bit worried about becoming reliant on Redux with React Navigation considering their website says: "Warning: in the next major version of React Navigation, to be released in Fall 2018, we will no longer provide any information about how to integrate with Redux and it may cease to work."

Comment: What they are talking about is that it is currently possible to put the navigation INTO redux too. It allow you to access the current scene and navigate with `dispatch`. I made multiple mobile apps with both lib in them without having to put the navigation into redux. If you keep your navigation as it is (separate from redux) the 2 libs should not interfere with one another. It would make no sense of react-navigation to say: `Yo! you must stop using Redux or stop using us!`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to re-render a React-Navigation screen view on navigating to it:

All credit goes to Andrei Pfeiffer, Jul 2018,  in his article: "Handle Tab changes in React Navigation v2" https://itnext.io/handle-tab-changes-in-react-navigation-v2-faeadc2f2ffe

I will reiterate it here in case the above link goes dead.

Simply add a NavigationEvents component to your render function with the desired listener prop:

```
  render() {
return (
      <View style={styles.view}>
      <NavigationEvents
          onWillFocus={payload => {
            console.log("will focus", payload);
            this.loadState();
          }}
        />
        <FlatList
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          style={styles.container}
          data={this.state.rows}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={extractKey}
        >
        </FlatList>
        <PostScreenFooter />
      </View>
    );
  }
```